# Interesting observation on byte addition and assignment

Tags: java, casting

Today while helping someone I came across an interesting issue which I couldn't understand the reason. 
While using += we don't need to explicit casting, but when we use i+i, we need to explicitly cast. Couldn't find exact reason. Any input will be appreciated.

```
public class Test{
       byte c = 2;
       byte d = 5;

       public  void test(String args[])
       {
           c += 2;
           d = (byte) (d + 3);   
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java is defined such that += and the other compound assignment operators automatically cast the result to the type of the variable being updated.  As a result, the cast isn't necessary when using +=, though it is necessary when just using the normal operators.  You can see this in the Java Language Specification at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

Specifically, the expression

```
a op= b
```

Is equivalent to

```
(a = (type of a)((a) op (b));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for quick response, can you provide any official refernce on this, if any?

Comment: I just updated the answer with the formal reference.  Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

From the Java [Language Spec, Chapter 15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> [..] the result of the binary operation *(Note: `(c+2)` in our example, which results in an `int` type value)* is converted to the type of the left-hand variable *(Note: to `byte` in our example)*, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.